# Serverside processing with CoideIgniter and Ignited-Datatables

Tags: codeigniter, server-side

I read many tutorial, I googled but I still can not figure out the problem. Something must be wrong, or I just simply do not understand a part of it.

I have some database tables which has over 10k rows. I want to load only 1 page (50 rows), and I want the processing to happen on paging, searching or at filtering and to not to load all rows from the database.

What am I missing? Thanks!

I am using the lastest version of codeigniter and ignited datatables.

Controller (for table creation):

```
$tmpl = array('table_open' => '<table id="logs" class="table table-striped table-hover">');
$this->table->set_template($tmpl);

$data['title'] = 'Activity log';

$this->table->set_heading('Time', 'User', 'Activity');

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
$this->load->view('logs/activity');
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

Controller (for data):

```
$this->datatables->select('id, log_change_id as activity, timestamp, users_id')
    ->from('log');

echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

View's content:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#logs').dataTable({
        "Processing": true,
        "ServerSide": true,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "timestamp" },
            { "data": "users_id" },
            { "data": "activity" }
        ],
        "ajax": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>database/activity',
        "language": {
            'sLoadingRecords': '<div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-5x fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></div>'
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My whole life was a lie. Changed this, to that and its working like charm.

```
"Processing": true,
"ServerSide": true,
```

That:

```
processing: true,
serverSide: true,
```